# API post method using urlsession showing error in swift

Tags: swift, api, post, urlsession

I have the parameters which has to be saved to database using post method api.
The property_image_url is `["https://res.cloudinary.com/dtwvevtm7/image/upload/v1617203478/j8mqat97ssrctsnzpjlc.jpg","https://res.cloudinary.com/dtwvevtm7/image/upload/v1617203479/j1rhedrsnrud7fkva1bl.jpg"]`

The parameters are as follows:

```
["price": "dry", "listing_description": "Dghb", "listing_type": "Residential", "property_image_url": "[\"https://res.cloudinary.com/dtwvevtm7/image/upload/v1617203478/j8mqat97ssrctsnzpjlc.jpg\",\"https://res.cloudinary.com/dtwvevtm7/image/upload/v1617203479/j1rhedrsnrud7fkva1bl.jpg\"]", "address": "chennai ", "listing_use": "SubLease", "property_video_url": "", "title": "huffy"]
```

Here when the value is property_image_url,it is showing unnescessary white space and escape character.

The code used to post the data via API is given below:

```
let url = URL(string: url)! //change the url

                    //create the session object
                    let session = URLSession.shared

                    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
                    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

                    do {
                        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: .fragmentsAllowed) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }

                     request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                     request.addValue(self.usertoken, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-token")

                    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
                    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                        
                        print("data is",data)

                        guard error == nil else {
                            return
                        }

                        guard let data = data else {
                            return
                        }

                        do {
                            //create json object from data
                            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                                print("new listing json is",json)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.navigationController?.view.makeToast("Listing Updated successfully", duration: 3.0, position: .bottom)
                                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! Home
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                                }
                            }
                        } catch let error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    })
                    task.resume()
}
```

This post method is throwing error saying

["errors": <__NSArrayM 0x283120810>(
Title Required,
Listing Type Required,
Listing Use Required
)
]

Here,in the parameter all these values are filled but still it is showing like that these values are empty.
Let me know what is the issue in passing the parameter and calling the API.

Comment: You are saying you'll give `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters but in fact your give JSON? Could it be that you need to put `application/json` for the Content-Type?

Comment: if i give as application/json,then the api is taking long time to process the request.It is taking around 15secs to get the response.How to make it faster?

Comment: Your current code seems correct. Is your connection good? Is your server quickly reachable? Is the request needing a long process on your server? Are you blocking your threads in the other part of your app? How do you know it's long?